# PostGis functions vs. EWKT

Tags: postgis, well-known-text

While using PostGis, we can query using EWKT format like:

```
SRID=4326;POINT(lon lat)
```

or use the functions defined by PostGis itself. For example:

```
ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint( lon , lat ) , 4326 )
```

I'm concerned if there are any kind of differences/preferences.

p.s. I'm sorry if it's a duplicate. I was unable to find any related threads.